# Div tags extending beyond their own margins

Tags: css, html

I have a weird issue that occurs regardless of browser (Chrome, IE, Opera Mobile Emulator are what I've tried).  I have divs nested within two other divs, as shown below.  These divs are all set to 100% width.  The innermost element drifts outside of (but stays "under") the parent divs.  I'm not floating anything, so I don't see why it is doing this.  Using overflow: hidden has no effect that I could see.  The image below shows Google Chrome's inspect element feature, which shows the element and padding extending beyond the margins (shown in the peach color).  I want everything to be within the margins as it should be.  I'm starting to think it may be something with the media queries I'm doing.  I am using these because a single percentage width won't always give me the exact width I want.  It's probably something shamefully stupid on my behalf, but has anyone ever seen anything like this?

### CSS

```
@media all and (max-width:960px)
{.container{width: 900px; } }

@media all and (max-width:1280px)
{.container{width: 1024px; }}

/*More media queries for a few other max resolutions*/

.container
{
  height: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
  border: 2px solid #13192D;
}

.midwrapper
{
  padding: 0px 12px;
  margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
  min-height: 420px;
}

.innermost
{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 8px auto;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: 2px solid #13192D;
}
```

[image: Margins]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

to

```
.innermost
```

Comment: Or simply remove 'width: 100%' from its style.

Comment: Both suggestions work.  I would have thought that 100% width on that would have made it 100% width of the parent, but whatever.  Thanks to you both.